# Grid and x and y coordinates

Tags: java, grid

I need to make a grid where the user inputs the number of asterisks in the columns and rows, so far I have this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grid {

public void run(){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the grid width (1-9):" );
        double num = scan.nextDouble(); 


        System.out.println("Enter the grid length (1-9)");
        double numLength = scan.nextDouble(); 


        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
           for(int j = 0; j < numLength; j++){
            System.out.print("*");
           }
        System.out.println("");
```

but I don't know how to insert a character 'X' into the (0,0) of the grid, the top left or how to make it move and even have it loop around. the user must put in "up" "down" "left" and "right" in order for it to move and I'm extremely confused on how to have x and y coordinates in java.

Comment: Inside your loop, `x` is `j`, and `y` is `i`. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out` is simple an output stream. You can't animate text on there, and you also can't register directional keys on the command line.

You need a GUI. It's not the best, but look into [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29).

A somewhat more messy approach is to repeatedly loop and get input from the user input via the command line:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter the grid width (1-9):" );
int w = scan.nextInt(); 

System.out.println("Enter the grid length (1-9):");
int h = scan.nextInt(); 

int x = 0, y = 0;
while (true)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < w; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < h; j++){
         if (i != x || j != y)
           System.out.print("*");
         else
            System.out.print("X");
      }
      System.out.println("");
   }
   System.out.println("Enter direction (u,d,l,r):");
   char c = scan.next().charAt(0);
   switch (c)
   {
      case 'u': x = Math.max(0, x-1); break;
      case 'd': x = Math.min(w-1, x+1); break;
      case 'l': y = Math.max(0, y-1); break;
      case 'r': y = Math.min(h-1, y+1); break;
      case 'x': System.out.println("Exiting..."); System.exit(0);
   }
}
```